# How to specify type for a swagger:parameters struct

Tags: go-swagger

My struct is defined as the following

```
// swagger:parameters instanceLogs
type SelectorParameter struct {
    // selector
    // in: query
    // required: false
    // type: string
    Selector uint `json:"selector"`
}
```

However the type show in my generated spec is uint64. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it correctly,
you haven't specified the length of it. so the system has decided about that.

I didn't get what exactly you want set for it, if you want it be `integer` use just `int` if you uint32 use `uint32`

```
// swagger:parameters instanceLogs
type SelectorParameter struct {
    // selector
    // in: query
    // required: false
    // type: string
    Selector int `json:"selector"`  // it will be Integer
}
```

[what is UINT](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-golang-type-uint)